# Nodeclipse does not show projects in Mint 17 64-bit

Tags: node.js, express, nodeclipse

I installed Enide Studio yesterday (decompressed the zip to /opt/enide-studio and had to make `eclipse` executable).  I then attempted to import an existing project.  It seemed to successfully import, but the project explorer shows nothing (it's completely blank).  I restarted the IDE, etc. -- still nothing.

Figuring it actually did not import the project, I tried again to import it this time from its git repo.  I was met with the error that the project already exists in the workspace; so, it's there, but the IDE is not showing it.

I then tried creating a new Node.js project.  It again seems to successfully create a project, but the UI is still white in all panels.  I see the perspective buttons for JS, Node, etc., but panels like Console are also completely blank white.

Also, attempting to create an express project fails outright because it can't find express (despite installing it as directed with `npm install -g express`).

I've logged out and back in as well as a reboot.  Still nothing...

Has anyone else encountered this and have a work-around/fix for Enide Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many issues put together as one.

Answering what is in question topic: "Nodeclipse does not show projects in Mint 17 64-bit"

Nodeclipse is plugin to Eclipse and displaying project in Project Explorer is implemented inside Eclipse core module called Eclipse Workbench. You can switch to other perspective e.g. Java and see that actually it displays the same list of projects.

General recommendation is to get latest Eclipse 4.4 Luna and install Nodeclipse (or get Enide Studio released after June 2014, not yet)

For other issues create separate tickets

http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support

Comment: I mentioned the other issues because I saw them as symptoms.  In posting to their site regarding Enide, they suggested I post here under Nodeclipse.  I figured this was likely because Enide appears to be just a packaged version of Eclipse with the plugin already installed.  In either case, the zipped version of Enide seems to be broken for Linux x64.  Downloading Luna separately and then installing Nodeclipse from the marketplace resolved the problem and symptoms/issues for me on Mint 17.